# 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

I am trying to reorder the chats in a tableView. The most recent updated chat should be insert at `IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1)`.
My understanding is that in order to delete a row, it must be visible.

If the row is not visible, when Data Source is updated, I just have to `tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndex], with: .fade)`.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of rows in section 1.  The number of rows contained in an
>   existing section after the update (17) must be equal to the number of
>   rows contained in that section before the update (17), plus or minus
>   the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted,
>   0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of
>   that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

```
//chats of the currentUser
var currentUserChats = [Chat]() {
    didSet(newValue){
       attachChildChangedObserverOn(chat: newValue)
    }
}

var observersArray = [String: UInt]() // chatUID: handle


//attach childChange listener on each chat downloaded
func attachChildChangedObserverOn(chat: Chat) {


    var handle: UInt = 0
    let ref =   DDatabaseRReference.chats.reference().child(chat.chatUID).child("users").child(currentUser.userUID)


    handle = ref.observe(.childChanged, with: {[weak self] (snapshot) in

        self?.observersArray[chat.chatUID] = handle

        guard snapshot.exists() else {return}

        let chatChanged = chat

        var lastMessage = ""
        var unreadMessagesCount = 0
        var lastUpdate = 0.0

        switch snapshot.key {

        case "lastMessage" :
           lastMessage = snapshot.value as! String
            chatChanged.lastMessage = lastMessage

        case "unreadMessagesCount":
             unreadMessagesCount = snapshot.value as! Int
             if let index = chatChanged.users.index(of: (self?.currentUser)!) {
                let userChanged = chatChanged.users[index]
                userChanged.unreadMessagesCount = unreadMessagesCount

                chatChanged.users.remove(at: index)
                chatChanged.users.insert(userChanged, at: index)
             }

        case "lastUpdate":
            lastUpdate = snapshot.value as! Double
            chatChanged.lastUpdate = lastUpdate

        default: return
        }


        let newIndex = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1)

         // get indexOf chatChanged
    guard let index = self?.currentUserChats.index(of: chatChanged) else {return}
          let indexPathOfOldChat = IndexPath(row: index, section: 1)

          // - update Data Source
          // - reloadRow
        if indexPathOfOldChat.row == 0 {
            self?.currentUserChats.remove(at: 0)
            self?.currentUserChats.insert(chatChanged, at: 0)
            self?.tableView.reloadRows(at: [newIndex], with: .fade)
            return
        }


        //get visible indexes of cells in TableView
        let visibleIndexes = self?.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows

         //check if the index of chat to be updated is visible
        if let indexes = visibleIndexes,
                   indexes.contains(indexPathOfOldChat) {

            //index is visible
           // update Data Source, delete row & insert row
            self?.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self?.currentUserChats.remove(at: indexPathOfOldChat.row)
            self?.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPathOfOldChat], with: .fade)

            self?.currentUserChats.insert(chatChanged, at: 0)
            self?.tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndex], with: .fade)
            self?.tableView.endUpdates()
            return
        }

        //if index is not visible:
        // - update Data Source
        // - insert the row
        self?.currentUserChats.remove(at: index)
        self?.currentUserChats.insert(chatChanged, at: 0)

        self?.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self?.tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndex], with: .fade)
        self?.tableView.endUpdates()
        return
    })
}
```

Comment: To update/delete a cell it's not required that it should be visible... You just refresh your data set and call tableview. reloadData()

Comment: @Pramod calling reloadData() is a bad idea, you don't reload the whole tableView just because you updated a label in a row.

Comment: @bibscy The only place you should update your data in cells is `cellForRow(at`. It will be called when you row will become visible and data will be automatically updated.

Comment: @Bohdan Savych  If you have an answer, please post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that rows that are not visible can be deleted.
Initially, I had thought that I would get an error if I tried to delete a row that was not visible because that cell for that row would no longer be in the view.

```
   //if index is not visible:
    // - update Data Source
    // - DELETE the previous row
    // - insert the new row

        self?.currentUserChats.remove(at: indexRow)
        self?.currentUserChats.insert(chatChanged, at: 0)

        self?.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self?.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPathOfOldChat], with: .none)
        self?.tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndex], with: .fade)
        self?.tableView.endUpdates()
        return
```